# Synchronization on Set element in java

Tags: java, java-8, synchronization

I have a set of unique elements. Each element have a set of operations that it can perform but each element operations are independent of other element operations. For instance there are three operations : O1, O2, O3 that each element can perform. Now each element can perform O1, O2, O3 without conflicting with other element. But each element when performing operation have to perform O1, O2, O3 exclusively(one at a time).

Is it a good way to take lock on the element in that case. Will it work? Is there also other way for instance with ReentrantLock or with java8 to do this in better way?

For e.g

```
for(Element element : elements) {
 synchronized(element) {
   //Perform O1,O2,O3 but one at a time
 }
}
```

Assume that above for loop can be called from multiple places and this for loop is written in multiple places in a code to perform different operation of a element.

Comment: You could just `synchronize` the methods O1, O2 and O3.  I don't like your loop above because 1. Any *other* caller must also remember to synchronize first before they call one of those methods, and 2. This externalizes what should be internal implementation.

Comment: whitch concrete implemention of Set do you use?

Comment: I am using Set derived from ConcurrentHashMap keySet.

Comment: Classes in `java.util.concurrent` provide memory visibility guarantees, but not in the case you outline above.  If the object must be synchronized somehow, then you have to synchronize the object.  Doing it any other way leaves large traps for anyone maintaining your code.

Comment: Is it required that the entire sequence `O1, O2, O3` is executed exclusively, i.e. that no other thread manipulates the object in-between these actions?

Answer (score 1):

As markspace suggests, the safest option is likely to be making your operations `synchronized`, rather than relying on all callers to do so properly, e.g.:

```
public class Element {
  public synchronized void O1() { ... }
  public synchronized void O2() { ... }
  public synchronized void O3() { ... }
}
```

This will ensure that, for a given instance of `Element`, only one operation is being invoked at a time. Your callers then don't need to worry about explicitly synchronizing anything:

```
for(Element element : elements) {
  element.O1();
  element.O2();
  element.O3();
}
```

However this won't be sufficient if you need to ensure these separate operations (O1, O2, and O3) all occur together, without interleaving with other possible callers. In that case the safest option would be to introduce new methods on `Element` that do what you need, rather than trying to compose them externally:

```
public class Element {
  // ...
  public synchronized void doAllOperations() { O1(); O2(); O3(); }
}
```

This ensures that everything in `doAllOperations()` will occur atomically with respect to any other invocation on this instant.